# like query against a subquery returning multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like:

```
select full_name, group_list from users;
```

that returns

```
Steve Jobs, ;1;2;3;5;
```

Then I have query like:

```
select GROUP_ID from group where GROUP_NAME LIKE 'APPLE80%'
```

that returns

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I'm trying to write a query that will tell me the users that are in any of the groups starting mit APPLE80% (see seconde query).

My attempts so far are ending with ORA-01427 - single-row subquery returns more than one row

Any ideas?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: A table definition and some example data would be helpful.

Comment: You should really have another table as the intersection between users and groups, rather than store many groups in a single value (which breaks First Normal Form).

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time I've found the answer, sorry:

```
select u.full_name, g.group_id, g.GROUP_NAME from user u, group g where g.GROUP_NAME LIKE 'APPLE80%' and u.group_list like '%;' || g.group_id || ';%'
```